# vba word linktolisttemplate won't work properly

Tags: list, vba, templates, ms-word, styles

I'm having trouble with this and don't know Why. I have a procedure to create some styles, some of them with linked list templates. I've this module inside the normal.dotm template (job stuff). The first time I executed this it worked ok and created all styles, including the linked to list ones. But after that, when I open word, linked to list styles appear unlinked and if I do the procedure again, it create them unlinked. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Here the code, CrearEstilos first delete all quickstyles and the created ones, then re-create and make them quickstyles

```
Dim aux As Integer
Sub CrearEstilos()
 BorrarEstilos
 Estilos
 EstilosRapidos
End Sub


Private Sub Estilos()
'Procedimiento para crear los estilos en caso necesario
    Dim t1 As Style, t2 As Style, t3 As Style, t4 As Style, pregunta As Style, respuesta As Style, recuer As Style, inde As Style
'Titulo nivel 1
If existe("Titulo nivel 1") = False Then
Set t1 = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Titulo nivel 1", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)

With t1
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 36
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel1
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)

End With
End If
'Titulo nivel 2
If existe("Titulo nivel 2") = False Then
Set t2 = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Titulo nivel 2", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)

With t2
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 16
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel2
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)

End With
End If
'Titulo nivel 3
If existe("Titulo nivel 3") = False Then
Set t3 = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Titulo nivel 3", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)

With t3


    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 14
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel3
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)

End With
End If
'Titulo nivel 4
If existe("Titulo nivel 4") = False Then
Set t4 = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Titulo nivel 4", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)

With t4
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 12
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel4
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)

End With
End If
'Titulo independiente
If existe("Titulo independiente") = False Then
Set t4 = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Titulo independiente", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)

With t4
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 11
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)

End With
End If
'Preguntas
If existe("Preguntas autoevaluacion") = False Then
Set pregunta = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Preguntas autoevaluacion", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)

With pregunta
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)

End With
End If
'Respuestas
If existe("Respuestas autoevaluacion") = False Then

Set respuesta = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Respuestas autoevaluacion", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)


With respuesta
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)
    .LinkToListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(5), _
                ListLevelNumber:=1
    End With
End If
'Recuerdas
If existe("Recuerdas unidad") = False Then

Set recuer = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="Recuerdas unidad", _
                                         Type:=WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)


With recuer
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)
    .LinkToListTemplate ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
                ListLevelNumber:=1
    End With
End If

ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
End Sub
Private Sub EstilosRapidos()
'Establece los estilos rápidos
Dim s As Style
'Primero borramos la lista
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
    If s.Type = wdStyleTypeCharacter Or _
        s.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or _
        s.Type = wdStyleTypeLinked Then

        s.QuickStyle = False

    End If

Next s
'Creamos los estilos
'Estilos
'Marcamos como rápidos los necesarios
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
    If s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 1" Or s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 2" Or s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 3" Or _
    s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 4" Or s.NameLocal = "Preguntas autoevaluacion" Or s.NameLocal = "Respuestas autoevaluacion" Or _
    s.NameLocal = "Recuerdas unidad" Or s.NameLocal = "Normal" Or s.NameLocal = "Titulo independiente" Then
        s.QuickStyle = True

    End If

Next s
End Sub
Private Sub BorrarEstilos()

'Establece los estilos rápidos
Dim r As Style
'Primero borramos la lista
For Each r In ActiveDocument.Styles
    If r.Type = wdStyleTypeCharacter Or _
        r.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or _
        r.Type = wdStyleTypeLinked Then

        r.QuickStyle = False

    End If

Next r
Dim s As Style
'Primero borramos la lista
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
    If s.NameLocal = "Recuerdas" Or s.NameLocal = "Respuestas" Or s.NameLocal = "Respuesta" _
    Or s.NameLocal = "Recuerda" Or s.NameLocal = "Variado" Or s.NameLocal = "probando" Or _
    s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 1" Or s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 2" Or s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 3" Or _
    s.NameLocal = "Titulo nivel 4" Or s.NameLocal = "Titulo independiente" Or s.NameLocal = "Preguntas" Then

        s.Delete

    End If

Next s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmmm I'm a rookie here but , although I don't understand why exactly, If you comment the line ...

```
ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
```

...your code works ok to me

Comment: Many thanks, this was bieng a pain in the ass. Thank you pal!